# Error commiting files to GitHub

Tags: github-for-windows

Whenever I try to commit a file to github i get the following error:

```
vanes@vanessaddiniz MINGW64 ~/HTML-CSS-and-JS---coursera/site (master)
$ git commit -m "Homepage"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'vanes@vanessaddiniz.(none)')
```

This is the frst time I try to do this. I've just started a course on coursera and I did everything exactly as done in the video and everythig was going fine until now. How do i fix this? Anyone who can help me, thanks in advance!

P.S: I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git always requires an identification while making a commit to a repository. The identification it uses is either your name or email address. This will be used to show commits which belong to users in Git history. The above output already shows you what you need to do. Run the below commands with your name and email address filled.

> git config --global user.email "Your email" 
>   git config --global user.name "Your Name"

After this you should be able to commit to git.

Comment: I've felt kind of stupid when I've finally got it some minutes ago hehehe. But thanks a lot anyway!